# do while loop breaking before it should

Tags: java

I'm learning to code java and at the moment I'm trying to make a basic game of "21".

There are two "do while" loops in the code:

1. where I want the player to choose whether he wants to draw a new card and
2. where I want the player to choose if he wants to play a new game when the last one finished.

However, it doesn't matter if I answer both questions with "Yes" or "No", the loop always breaks and "ends".

Is there something wrong in my logic?

Thanks a lot for the help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class twentyOneGame {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int computerCard;
    int playerCard;
    int playerSumCards = 0;
    int computerSumCards = 0;
    int cardAmount = 0;
    String keepPlaying = "Yes";
    String keepGoing;


    System.out.printf("Enter your name %n");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String playerName = input.nextLine();

    do {
        do {

            playerDraw playerdraw = new playerDraw();
            playerCard = playerdraw.getPlayerCard();
            playerSumCards += playerCard;

            computerDraw computerdraw = new computerDraw();
            computerCard = computerdraw.getComputerCard();
            computerSumCards += computerCard;
            cardAmount += 1;

            System.out.printf("Your have %s card(s). Your total is %s. %n", cardAmount, playerSumCards);

            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.printf("Do you want to draw another card? Yes or No %n");
            keepGoing = input.nextLine();

        } while (keepGoing == "Yes" && cardAmount < 3);


        if (cardAmount == 1) {
            System.out.printf("Your total is %s %n", playerSumCards);
            System.out.printf("The computers total is %s %n", computerSumCards);

            if (playerSumCards > computerSumCards) {
                System.out.printf("Good job %s, you won! %n", playerName);
            } else {
                if (playerSumCards == computerSumCards) {
                    System.out.printf("It's a draw! %n");
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("Oh no, the computer won! %n");
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (cardAmount == 2) {

                System.out.printf("Your total is %s %n", playerSumCards);
                System.out.printf("The computers total is %s %n", computerSumCards);

                if (playerSumCards > computerSumCards) {
                    System.out.printf("Good job %s, you won! %n", playerName);
                } else {
                    if (playerSumCards == computerSumCards) {
                        System.out.printf("It's a draw! %n");
                    } else {
                        System.out.printf("Oh no, the computer won! %n");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (cardAmount == 3) {

                    System.out.printf("Your total is %s %n", playerSumCards);
                    System.out.printf("The computers total is %s %n", computerSumCards);

                    if (playerSumCards > computerSumCards) {
                        System.out.printf("Good job %s, you won! %n", playerName);
                    } else {
                        if (playerSumCards == computerSumCards) {
                            System.out.printf("It's a draw! %n");
                        } else {
                            System.out.printf("Oh no, the computer won! %n");
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Do you want to keep playing? Yes or No %n");
        keepPlaying = input.nextLine();

        if (keepPlaying == "Yes") {
            playerSumCards = 0;
            computerSumCards = 0;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Thanks for playing, %s %n", playerName);
            break;
        }

    } while (keepPlaying =="Yes");
}
}
```

Comment: keepGoing == "Yes".... never ever!!

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Sorry I didn't know where/what the issue was, so that's why I couldn't actively search for the answer. I've tried several topics. Thanks so much!